# Extract integer from list using python

Tags: python, list, tuples

Extract integer from list

```
test = query_database("SELECT SUM(try) FROM tries where number=?", (nb,))
print test
```

The result i got is **[(100,)]**

And when i extract value from list as :

```
for i in test:
      print i
```

the result is **(100,)**

How to extract only **100** as integer with no parenthesis and commas ?

Comment: `i[0]`? Just access the first element in the tuple.

Comment: Thanks Andrew Li, it works.

Answer (score 1):

Since your list consists of tuples you have to first get the tuples then the value in the tuple something like this

```
for i in test:
     for j in i: #itertae the tuple like list
         print(j)
```

Answer (score 0):

The returned value is a list of tuples. Retrieving the elements of tuple can be done by indexing.

```
for i in test:
    print i[0]
```